# Show that all eigenvalues of a graph $G$ a are equal to $0 \iff G$ is a null graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have an idea that I think may work for the first direction, but not quite sure. Can anyone help? Here is my initial idea:

> Assume all eigenvalues of $G$ are $0$.
>
> Then, all eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots \lambda_n$  of the associated nxn adjacency matrix A of G are 0. Thus, for a corresponding eigenvector $x$ to eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have by definition
>
> $Ax = \lambda x$
>   $\implies \ Ax = 0 \implies A = 0$
>
> Hence, $A$ is the null matrix and thus $G$ contains no edges.

I'm not exactly certain of my logic here as I want $G$ to contain no vertices in order to be a null graph... and I'm not sure what else I can say after this.

The second direction is much simpler since it follows from $G$ being null, hence having a null adjacency matrix and all eigenvalues of a null matrix are $0$.

Any help is much appreciated; thanks in advance!

Comment: The original statement is wrong: A graph with $n$ vertices has $n \times n$ adjacency matrix, so it is null iff $n = 0$. You have already shown all that you can show, which is that the graph has no edges.

Comment: @Travis Thank you for your comment, that makes a lot more sense than the original statement!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is in general not true, for a reason you pointed out. Any graph with no edges has the zero matrix as its adjacency matrix, regardless of how many vertices it has. However, we *can* prove the following statement:

> Let $G$ be an undirected graph, and $A$ be its adjacency matrix. If every eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, then $G$ has no edges.

Try to prove this. Here are two hints if you need them:

> The adjacency matrix of an undirected graph is symmetric. Symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable.

Additionally, try to find a counterexample to the above statement if we drop the requirement that $G$ be undirected.

Comment: I was wondering why it made no sense to me to go any further; my instructor gave this exact question for homework and I figured I'd come here for help! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Carah Of course! Glad it was helpful.